# if the limit of $f(x)$ is $4$ (as $x$ approaches $6$), what is the limit of $f(x)^2$?

Tags: limits

As the title suggests, is it as simple as squaring the 4 to get 16? Or would I need to incorporate the value it's approaching somehow?(6)

Likewise, a similar scenario if the limit of f(x) = 3 and g(x) = 1(as they approach -4), what would be g(x)/x^2?

Would I simply put the 1 over 3^2?

Comment: Apply the $\varepsilon$/$\delta$ definition of $\lim$ and show that $$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L \implies \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)^2 = L^2.$$

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties